# What are the valid [].forEach.call function argument?

Tags: javascript, html

What are the valid `[].forEach.call` function argument? In the code below `el` appears to be a `Nodelist` or an element of the nodelist?

```
[].forEach.call(
    document.getElementById('menu').querySelectorAll('.custom-can-transform'),
       function(el){
           el.classList.toggle('pure-menu-horizontal');
       }
    );
)
```

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: You do know that NodeList has a forEach method right?

Comment: [ECMAScript 5.1, 15.4.4.18](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18): "_The forEach function is intentionally generic; it does not require that its this value be an Array object. Therefore it can be transferred to other kinds of objects for use as a method. Whether the forEach function can be applied successfully to a host object is implementation-dependent._"

Comment: @evolutionxbox — Only with much more limited browser support

Comment: @Quentin oh rly? I did not know this

Comment: how did el referenced a nodelist element, in function(el), what if I had function(el1, el2)?

Answer (score 0):

Many of the Array methods are generic by design. It means that their internal implementation doesn't rely in `this` to be `Array` instance. Basically, such implementation only requires this object to have numeric indexes and `length` property. Such objects are called "array-like objects".

There are many objects that conform this requirements. For example NodeList observed by you as `document.getElementById('menu').querySelectorAll`. This is array-like object because you can access individual Nodes by their indexes, and such node list have `length` property.

Any string is array-like object too. For example, string "hello world". you can access character "w" as `str[t]`. And `str.length` is equal to 11.

Requirement of numeric indexes and `length` property allows method implementation to iterate through all individual element of collection without need to know what this collection is actually is.

It also make it possible to use generic methods on different objects:

```js
const obj = {0: 'one', 1: 'two', length: 2};

Array.prototype.forEach.call(obj, (el, index) => {
  console.log(`${index}: ${el}`)
})
```

Or, the most common use for such "borrowed" other prototype methods is using array methods on non arrays, usually DOM elements:

```
const items = document.querySelector('ul > li')

const ids = [].map.call(items, li => li.id)
```

---

Here I should note, that [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) from ES2015 spec, makes such borrowing methods less needed.

Answer (score 0):

[Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) replaces the `this` variable of the function with its first argument, and then calls the function with all remaining arguments given to `.call()`.

This means that the code above evaluates to this:

```
document.getElementById('menu').querySelectorAll('.custom-can-transform').forEach(function(el){
  el.classList.toggle('pure-menu-horizontal');
});
```

Note that the `this` variable of `forEach` without use of the `.call()` method would be `[]`, as it prefixes the `forEach` call.

As to what the arguments of `forEach` on an array are?

It only accepts 2 arguments. The first argument is the function `callback` that gets called for each element of the array. The second (optional) argument is used to inject a `this` variable into the function-body of the callback method. [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)